# Setting up Email Portlet in Browsercms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, browsercms

How to use Email Portlet provided by Brosercms to setup a mailer ?
I am getting the following error if i directly use the email-portlet(with the pre-defined template) in one of my website pages: ERROR: undefined method `cms_handler_path' for #&ltCms::ViewContext:0xb532040&gt

Comment: Can you post some code? That error is raised when you are missing a route and try to reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserCMS has been updated to Rails 3 however, this cms_handler_path routes is not updated in the email_page_porlets. Change it to cms_path, then it should be working fine. Basically it needs to be able to call the EmailPagePortlet's deliver action.

Remember to set up your action_mailer configuration